# JavaScript Regex - Get Nth digits from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a date string being output in this format: `2014-11-28 00:00:00`

I'm getting the year with JS match and regex to grab the first four digits: `match(/^[0-9]{4}/)`

So now I'd like to get the month and the day too. If they are below 10, a 0 is prepended, so I thought the simplest way would be to pull the 6th and 7th characters for the month and the 8th and 9th characters for the day.

How can I do this with regex in jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: How are you wanting the output?

Comment: Why not split the first 8 characters on : so you don't need the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can done this using `match()` or `split()`.

**Using `match()`:**

```
var date = '2014-11-28 00:00:00',
    pattern = /^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/
    dateElements = date.match(pattern),
    day = dateElements[3],
    month = dateElements[2],
    year = dateElements[1];
alert('Day = ' + day + ', Month = ' + month + ' & Year = ' + year);
```

**Or Using `split()`:**

```
var date = '2014-11-28 00:00:00',
    str = date.substring(0, date.length - 9),
    dateElements = str.split('-'),
    day = dateElements[2],
    month = dateElements[1],
    year = dateElements[0];
alert('Day = ' + day + ', Month = ' + month + ' & Year = ' + year);
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can try a different approach to your problem instead of regex?

The [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object seems to be sufficient for your purposes.

```
var d = new Date('2014-11-28 00:00:00');
d.getFullYear(); // returns 2014
d.getMonth(); // return 10
d.getDay(); // returns 28
```

If you really want to use regular expressions, this will capture the groups as you wish:

```
var foo = '2014-11-28 00:00:00'.match(/^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/);
foo[1]; // returns "2014"
foo[2]; // returns "11"
foo[3]; // returns "28"
```

Read more about [regex capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: The date method didn't seem to work - I kept getting NaN errors. The regex way worked though, thanks :)

Comment: The date method requires that the date match the exact format as you provided, known as ISO 8601. It also requires IE 9+ but apart from that, should work on all modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will work for your purposes:

```
/^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/
```